# find the minimum cost conversion between currencies A and B, given a matrix of currency conversions

Tags: algorithms

Given a matrix of currency conversions, find the minimum cost conversion between currencies A and B (ex. maybe min cost conversion is A->C->D->B)

I was thinking of this as some sort of max flow problem such that A and B are the source and sink respectively, but I can't figure out exactly how to transform the weights of the problem.

Comment: Maybe it's A→B→C→A→B→C→… _ad infinitum_

Comment: @PålGD this is a shortest path-finding problem. So if there is a negative cycle, of course there is no solution. However when there isn't a negative cycle, we can compute the solution easily using an existing technique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pathfinding algorithm for this case:

Create a node for each currency type.

Add an edge between two currency types if you can directly convert between them (in the case of your problem, you always can). For now, lets put the currency conversion rate as the weight of the edge - but this will change later on.

Say you want to convert between currency $A$ and $B$, then you will want to follow the path $p:=v_0,v_1,\dots,v_k$ such that $\Pi_{i=1}^{k-1} w(v_i,v_{i+1})$ is minimized.

Notice that by applying $\log$ on the formula, and using the fact that $log$ is monotonic, we get that this is exactly the path with $\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \log(w(v_i,v_{i+1}))$ minimized.

Therefore, by changing the weights to their logarithm (the weights will now be $log(conversion\_rate(v_i,v_{i+1}))$ instead of just $conversion\_rate(v_i,v_{i+1})$),  we get that a shortest path is exactly what you need. You can use here Djikstra, or any other pathfinding algorithm you prefer.